# Controller to render all Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC4.
I have an application that uses numerous partial views, currently I have a controller that I am using to return PartialView for each of them, makeing a very long file.

```
public PartialViewResult somePartial()
    {
        return PartialView("someParital");

    }
public PartialViewResult someOtherPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("someOtherParital");

    }
```

Is there a way to create a controller that would return PartialView for an entire folder/directory?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you doing with these partial views?  It seems unlikely that you would actually need to have your own method for returning partial views.  Maybe if you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve we can possibly show you a better way to accomplish your end-result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render `Partial Views` directly into the markup using `HTML Helper`. The easiest way could be store every `Partial View` name into a `List` somewhere, and then use it to render every `Partial View` by name.

```
@{
    var myPartialViews = new string[] { "someParital", "someOtherParital" };
 }

@foreach(string partialView in myPartialViews)
{
    Html.Partial(partialView) //or Html.RenderPartial(partialView);
}
```

Comment: If you use `Html.Partial`, you have to use a `@` since it returns a string and will go to nowhere. If you use `Html.RenderPartial` it will write the string in the response and you don't need the nuget.

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple partial View Using return Json Data as string of PartialView  as describe here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18978036/2318354

```
return Json(new {  strPartial1 = RazorViewToString.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "someParital", model) ,  strPartial12 = RazorViewToString.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "someOtherParital", model2) });
```

Now instead of using UpdateTargetId On Success function do following way Ajax Request

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link-Name", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "scsFunction" })
```

on javaScript

```
function scsFunction(response) {
    var temphtml1 = response.strPartial1 ;
    var temphtml2 = response.strPartial2 ;

    $("#dvPartial1").html(temphtml1);
    $("#dvPartial2").html(temphtml2);

    }
```

This way you can update number of Partial View at One Action Call